# How to use different vhost config files for Apache with SNI & multiple SSL certificates?

Tags: apache

Ran into an issue with one of our setups, not to sure if that's even possible.

We're running a simple Ubuntu 18.04LTS server with PHP-FPM and Apache installed, that will host over a dozen different sites, with at least half of them having different SSL certificates. The server only has a single IP address/NIC.

To make everything easier to manage, I had initially created different vhost config files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, so every site would have their own; this was causing issues as one of the sites would be deemed "default" for SSL and its certificate would be handed out to all the other sites.

Going through StackOverflow and the internet, I've found a lot of posts that were saying to have a single vhost config file with all of our different site configurations...but now I have a thousand line config file, which is a mess to manage.

Is there a way to use SNI, with a single IP/NIC, with different vhost config files, or is our setup "uncommon" and we'll need to use a single vhost config file ?

Thanks!

EDIT: Link to a copy of the vhost config we use, sanitized of course: https://pastebin.com/1tQYBSxR

Comment: It is possible to configure multiple vhosts, with different certs. If this did not work for you, then you did something wrong (but we will need to see an example config to see exactly what)

Comment: @DusanBajic, I've added in my post a pastebin of my vhost config.

Comment: That is only one vhost, solution requires one vhost per site (you said "I had initially created different vhost config files in /etc/apache2/sites-available, so every site would have their own", can you share at least 'default' one and another one)

Comment: @DusanBajic, yes I know. Each vhost config file has the same configuration, but with a different SSL Cert path, ServerName, and document root. There's no "default" config, as each website URL has it's own config file in `sites-available`.

Comment: Vhost conf is applied based on unique `ServerName`+`IP`+`port` combination. Port and IP address are usually the same, which leaves ServerName (or ServerAlias) to make distinction. If your vhosts had different ServerName but still only one vhost configuration was always applied, then there was something wrong with your config

Comment: I don't think you understand my setup, because you keep saying my config was wrong. The content of my Pastebin is what I had in each "domain.com.conf" file, in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. `ServerName` was in each config file, and it was different for each config file. Each URL had its own file. This did not work. All I did to make it work, was merge all of them into a single file, and then it worked.

Comment: I understand. What do (or did) you have in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Apache works for SSL VirtualHosts *by default*:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site1.com
    # Certs definitions for site1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site2.com
    # Certs definitions for site2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site3.com
    # Certs definitions for site3.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you would expect that when a client connects with one of the sites, Apache understands which site it wants and uses that certificate, right?

But that is not the case.  Apache does **not** know which site is asked for until **after** SSL negotiation is done.  It must therefore always use the first VirtualHost certificate.

`NameVirtualHost` (Apache 2.2 directive, always on in v2.4) does not work for SSL.

---

You **can** put the definitions of each domain in a separate file.  As long as they are all `Include`d in the global config file.  But again, only the first defined VirtualHost will serve *.443 requests.

In fact I have managed Apache servers with ~50 VirtualHost definitions, and having them all in one file would have been a nightmare.  Split them by domain.  You can even name the file THE_DOMAIN.conf.

---

Now how to get rid of that problem:

- have 1 IP per domain.  Which means 1 IP per VirtualHost.  That way Apache knows which site the user requested, right form the start.  But that requires as many addresses as you have domains.
- have 1 port per domain.  Instead of using port 443, some sites could use a non-default port.  But that is weird for clients who have to specify the port in the request.  Ex. https://example.com:445/.  In enterprise setups, you can get your firewall-nat-proxy to change the port back for the client, but this is out of scope of this answer.  This might be blocked as they are not default ports.
- use SNI.  This is supported by modern browsers, where the identification of the desired domain is sent at the time of SSL negotiation.

Using SNI is detailed here (and other references on the web) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Overview:

- the first VirtualHost is still the default used for clients that do not support SNI (older browser for example).
- A new directive was added: `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck`
- You must use a minimum version of OpenSSL on the host, and Apache must have been compiled with it.  It must enable TLS extensions.

Have fun!